# BindingList.Clear() doesn't clear the List

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety, bindinglist

I have a BindingList and I want to clear it at some Point and refill it with new objects. For some reason, the Clear-Method does not work sometimes. Could be because of a race condition because the Clear-Method and the adding of new objects is called in an event-handler.

Here is how I do it:

```
mydropdown_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myBindingList.Clear();
    foreach(object obj in AnotherListWithObjects)
    {
        object bindingObject = SomeInitializationMethod(obj);
        myBindingList.Add(bindingObject);
    }
}
```

Problem is that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't clear the list . So some objects are added multiple times, which leads to an exception later in my program.

Is there a way to force my BindingList to clear without having to remove every object by itself or by creating a new BindingList? I think those are bad ways to do that. Maybe somehow wait for it to be able to clear or force it to do so. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

### Edit 1

I was able to determine, that the event-handler and thereby the shown code is run twice 'simultaneously' because of that, it's difficult to debug it with Visual Studio. I tried using *lock* on my BindingList but that too doesn't work.

### Edit 2

As suggested by [hiule](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8012407/hiule), some more code. Sadly I can't post it all:

So basically, I have a dropdown control. That dropdown validates itself, when it loses focus, as every control does.

I have a save-method, that's called via button click. All my controls lay on some LayoutControl. Lets call it 'basecontrol'. When I press the save-button, it first validates all controls again.

```
mySaveButton_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    basecontrol.ValidateChildren()
    // Saving input
}
```

So, when I give my dropdown focus and remove it by clicking my savebutton, the dropdown validates twice. Once because the loss of focus, once because of the explicit call to validate.

I realize that I can simply leave out the explicit call to validate but I think it's better to validate right before saving so that no values can ba altered in-between. I would really appreciate a solution that would just allow the BindingList to be cleared in both cases. It might be redundant but it's a very short task and as I said, I want the validation right before saving.

Comment: can you show all related code?

Comment: You can't access the list from multiple-threads at all - even reading isn't safe. Make sure you only ever access the list from one thread at a time - ideally, only on the UI thread.

Comment: @hiule: I cant add much code but I added some and explained the situation a little bit more. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Luaan: How can I do that? As I stated in my edit, I tried to lock it, but that doesnt work either.